# Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length - JS engine bug? See the code example

Tags: javascript, arrays

Yesterday I spent half a day to find the issue, I not novice, project is quite big. Below is the piece of primitive code with array which has only 7 STRING items. So question: why there is such not relevant error as "RangeError: invalid array length" is there? I found the reason - but I can not find any information that this is normal behaviour for js engine. Doesn work in: Chrome, Edge, Firefox (07th May 2020).

```
<script>
        let selected_options = [];
        let keys = ['title', 'size', 'color', 'weight', 'length', 'width', 'height'];
        //keys.length === 7
        for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            selected_options[keys[i]] = `here is the key ${keys[i]}`;
        }

        console.table(selected_options);
    </script>
```

Comment: Please don't create tags like 'length' and 'invalid' they are not useful

Comment: Why did you initialize `selected_options` as an _array_, if you then try to use non-numeric keys? Sounds like you actually rather want an _object_ to begin with.

Comment: ^ On an array you can't set the length to a string. `[].length = "here is the key length"` will produce the error.

Comment: Since arrays _are_ objects, you can of course add new object properties to them this way in general. Your code does that fine for the first four keys in your list. But `length` is a property arrays already have, and the values it can take has specific restrictions (such as, needs to be an integer in the first place.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set non-integer length for an array. This is normal behavior of JS engine as per [ECMA-262 spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/) as follows:

[`[[DefineProperty]]`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array-exotic-objects-defineownproperty-p-desc) for Array exotic object states if property is "length", call [`ArraySetLength`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-arraysetlength), which in return checks and throws the above `RangeError`:

```
3. Let newLen be ? ToUint32(Desc.[[Value]]).
4. Let numberLen be ? ToNumber(Desc.[[Value]]).
5. If newLen ≠ numberLen, throw a RangeError exception.
```

As comments have already mentioned, you should be using a regular object or `Map` here.